# Drill down tables in Shiny - nested child-parents tables

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, shinydashboard

I am want to replicate an excel dashboard in shiny - I need to create nested data tables such that it displays aggregated data at country levels and when you click on a country it opens nested districts and data corresponding to them. See screenshots.
Country, District, and Mechanism are 3 different columns in the dataset

[image]

When you click on the '+' sign table opens up to show data at the district level and then at the mechanism level
[image]

Comment: Maybe [this](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/002-rowdetails.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! But, is there a way to do this without JS?